# Create list for dropdownlist in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i'm using this ViewModel

```
public class SliderViewModel
{
    public Models.Slider Slider { get; set; }
    public System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Priorities { get; set; }
    public int Selected_Priority { get; set; }
}
```

now i want to create list to bind to dropdownlist in view

```
IList<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> list = new IList<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>();

for (int i = 1; i <= SliderCount; i++)
{
    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() });
}

objSlider.Priorities = list;
```

i'm using this code but get an error
**Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
IList<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> list = new List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>();
```

notice the right-hand said is type `List`.

You cannot directly instantiate an interface, that's a rule of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
IList<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> list = new IList<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>();
```

should be

```
IList<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> list = new List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>();
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be a typo in the following line

```
IList<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> list = new IList<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>();
```

You cannot instantiate an interface. Instead, create an object `List` that implements the interface `IList`